# get html content from react array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get an html inside a react array that i use in render method.
First of all i create my content with something like this:

```
    let resultHtml = [];

    resultHtml.push(<p key="resultScore"> Score: {currentResult} </p>);

    if (Number(currentResult) < 0.5) {

        resultHtml.push(<p key="resultScoreDesc"> Assenza di Fibrosi </p>);
    }

    else if (Number(currentResult) > 0.5 && Number(currentResult) < 1.2) {

        resultHtml.push(<p key="resultScoreDesc">Fibrosi da F1 a F4, necessita di ulteriori indagini per chiarire il grado di fibrosi</p>);
    }

    else if (Number(currentResult) > 1.5) {

        resultHtml.push(<p key="resultScoreDesc">Cirrosi </p>);
    }
```

then i want the pure html inside resultHtml array for save it in a database:

```
 let dataForSave = {

        id: this.props.scoreId,
        title: this.state.title,
        description: this.state.description,
        form: form,
        result : resultHtml.join()
    }
```

i try to use join() method but the string is empty. 
is there a way or i need to use a simple string?

Comment: I dn think you are pushing HTML into `resultHtml`. You are pushing JSX.

Comment: do you really want to store HTML ?? Looks like you are forming them based on few conditions. Won't storing the neaded variables and generate the html later when required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at ReactDOMServer, this is the way React implements Universal applications:

[enter link description here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html)

This should do what you need:

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line, for example.

`resultHtml.push(<p key="resultScoreDesc"> Assenza di Fibrosi </p>);`

You're pushing an object into the array and then trying to join multiple objects. Instead, try pushing each line of HTML as a string, and then store it into the db, as such:

`resultHtml.push("<p key='resultScoreDesc'> Assenza di Fibrosi </p>");`

Notice the quotes surrounding the HTML.

Then when you pull your strings out of the DB, you can ["dangerously set HTML"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html) in the React app to escape the HTML. Obviously, be careful what HTML you inject, because it leaves you vulnerable to XSS.